# How to fix TV stream over VLC Android crashes instantly, yet plays on Windows?

Tags: streaming, chromecast, vlc

I have a FRITZ!Box 6690 Cable that offers TV streams. I can watch TV on the official Fritzbox TV App on my One Plus 9 Pro (Oxygen 13.1), I can open the stream on Windows through VLC and it plays fine.

Yet, my goal is to cast the signal to Chromecast. The official app doesn't feature a cast button, so I'm trying VLC.

Yet, on both Chromecast and my Android phone, the stream plays for a couple of milliseconds (I see a bunch of frames and hear the sound, so it's actually playing the stream), only to exit immediately.

How can I force VLC on Chromecast to play the stream?

Comment: @k0pernikus The "official Fritzbox TV App" you mention, on what platform is it executed? What Chromecast do you have? AFAIR there are three or four different versions with different capabilities.

Comment: @Robert Oxygen 13.1, yet the app has no "Cast to Chromecast" feature.